# More efficient way to copy repeating sequence into TypedArray?

Tags: javascript, iteration, bit-manipulation, typed-arrays

I have a source `Float32Array` that I create a secondary `Float32Array` from. I have a sequence of values `model` that I want to copy as a repeating sequence into the secondary `Float32Array`. I am currently doing this operation using a reverse while loop.

```
sequence = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0];
n = 3179520; //divisible by sequence length
modelBuffs = new Float32Array(n);

var v = modelBuffs.length;

while(v-=12){
  modelBuffs[v-12] = sequence[0];
  modelBuffs[v-11] = sequence[1];
  modelBuffs[v-10] = sequence[2];
  modelBuffs[v-9] = sequence[3];

  // YTransform
  modelBuffs[v-8] = sequence[4];
  modelBuffs[v-7] = sequence[5];
  modelBuffs[v-6] = sequence[6];
  modelBuffs[v-5] = sequence[7];

  // ZTransform
  modelBuffs[v-4] = sequence[8];
  modelBuffs[v-3] = sequence[9];
  modelBuffs[v-2] = sequence[10];
  modelBuffs[v-1] = sequence[11];
}
```

Unfortunately, `n` can be unknown. I may have to do a significant refactor if there is no alternative solution. I am hoping that I can set the sequence once and there is a copy in place/ repeating fill / bitwise operation to repeat the initial byte sequence.

*Edit* simplified the example input

Comment: As per what I can see, you have a pattern, but you are not using values at `3, 7,11,15`. Any specific reason?

Comment: @rajesh I clipped this from a more involved example. The specific reason are 3,7,11,15 are the last column of a 4x4 matrix that are not used

Comment: So should we assume that in a `NxM` matrix, `m-1` column is always not used?

Comment: I will edit the example to simplify this so it's not distracting. The problem still stands. How to copy in place a repeating byte sequence

Comment: There's the [copyWithin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/copyWithin) method, but it's not necessarily faster than a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fast method to fill an array with a repeated sequence, is to double up length of buffer for each iteration using the [`copyWithin()`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/typedarray/copywithin) method of the typed array. You could use [`set()`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/typedarray/set) as well by creating a different view for the same underlying `ArrayBuffer`, but it's simpler to use the former for this purpose.

Using for example `1234` as source, the first initial iteration fill will be 1:1, or 4 indices in this case:

```
1234
```

From there we will use destination buffer as source for the remaining fill, so second iteration fills 8 indices:

```
12341234
```

Third iteration fills 16 indices:

```
1234123412341234
```

Fourth iteration fills 32 indices:

```
12341234123412341234123412341234
```

and so forth.

If the last segment length doesn't match power of 2 you can simple do a diff between last fill and the length remaining in the buffer and use that for the last iteration.

```js
var 
  srcBuffer = new Uint8Array([1,2,3,4]), // any view type will do
  dstBuffer = new Uint8Array(1<<14),     // 16 kb
  len = dstBuffer.length,   // important: use indices length, not byte-length
  sLen = srcBuffer.length,
  p = sLen;                 // set initial position = source sequence length

var startTime = performance.now();

// step 1: copy source sequence to the beginning of dest. array
// todo: dest. buffer might be smaller than source. Check for this here.
dstBuffer.set(srcBuffer);

// step 2: copy existing data doubling segment length per iteration
while(p < len) {
  if (p + sLen > len) sLen = len - p;  // if not power of 2, truncate last segment
  dstBuffer.copyWithin(p, 0, sLen);    // internal copy
  p += sLen;                           // add current length to offset
  sLen <<= 1;                          // double length for next segment
}

var time = performance.now() - startTime;
console.log("done", time + "ms");
console.log(dstBuffer);
```

If the array is very long it will obviously take some time regardless. In those cases you could consider using a [Web Worker](https://devdocs.io/dom/web_workers_api) with the new [`SharedArrayBuffer`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/sharedarraybuffer) so that you can do the copying in a different process and not have to copy or transfer the data to and from. The gain from this is merely that the main thread is not blocked with little overhead dealing with the buffer as the internals of `copyWithin()` is relative optimal for its purpose already. The cons are the async aspect combined with the overhead from the event system (e.g.: it depends if this is useful).

A different approach is to use [WebAssembly](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/webassembly) where you write the buffer fill code in C/C++, compile and expose methods to take source and destination buffers, then call that from JavaScript. I don't have any example for this case.

In both of these latter cases you will run into compatibility issues with (not that much) older browsers.